# XSLT: wrap text without converting into string

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

Is there a way to wrap a specific part of a node without losing child-elements by converting them into a string?

That's what i've got:

```
<root>
    <caption>Figure 3.1 Description of an Image, sometimes with <inline>Bold</inline> or <inline>Italic</inline> emphases.</caption>
</root>
```

... and that's what I need:

```
<root>
    <caption><inline>Figure 3.1</inline>Description of an Image, sometimes with <inline>Bold</inline> or <inline>Italic</inline> emphases.</caption>
</root>
```

I tought about using a regex `^Figure\s[0-9]+.[0-9]+` to catch different variations (e.g. Figure 11.10) and tried for hours to solve the problem, but couldn't do it without deleting the following `<inline>`'s ... is it even possible?

I'm using XSLT 2.0!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a template for the text nodes

```
<xsl:template match="caption/text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^Figure\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <inline><xsl:value-of select="."/></inline>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course you start the stylesheet with the identity transformation template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works just fine! I've tried the same solution before, but failed because of a ThinSpace (&#x2009;) between "Figure" and the Numbers...